# Drupal hook_form_alter: how to target only node/edit and NOT node/add. Aso, why #disabled doesn´t work?

Tags: drupal, hook-form-alter

I want to disable a cck field inside a specific form in Drupal 6.
I´ve created a new module full of alterations, using hook_form_alter.
The form id is articulo_node_form. The field in question is text, [I´ve checked](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6) and it can be disabeled.

I´ve tried this:

```
function modding_form_articulo_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_articulo_tipo']['#disabled'] = 1;
}
```

The field doesn´t disable at all, instead, **it dissappears**.

Anyway that happens when I try to create a new articulo node or when I try to edit that node. **I want to target only node edits**, I mean, the same form, but when it´s being edited.

What´s wrong with that code?
THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!

Rosamunda

Comment: Try `$form['field_articulo_tipo']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';`

Comment: Brilliant! THANKS CLIVE! Is there any way to set a comment as best reply? Because that did the trick!

Comment: Or you could just post this as reply and I would mark it as the best :)

Comment: @RosamunaRosamunda You're more than welcome! I'll put this in an answer, who knows it might help someone else in the future too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a reason why the code you've got wouldn't work but you can use code like this to 'force' the attribute to be displayed:

```
$form['field_articulo_tipo']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
```